# How to setMethodHandler onTaskRemoved using flutter channel

Tags: java, flutter, kotlin

I want to use the hook when android calls onTaskRemoved in my app.

This is my kotlin MainActivity class.
It works well when I implement setMethodCallHandler.

```kotlin
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.Bundle
import android.util.Log
import io.flutter.embedding.android.FlutterActivity
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineCache
import io.flutter.plugin.common.MethodChannel

class MainActivity: FlutterActivity() {
    private val CHANNEL_HANDLER = "buddhism.supporter.onTaskRemoved"

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        var i = Intent(this, TaskService::class.java)


        flutterEngine?.dartExecutor?.let {
            MethodChannel(it.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL_HANDLER).setMethodCallHandler {
                call, result ->
                if (call.method.equals("startService")) {
                    FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().put("engine_id", flutterEngine)
                    startService(i)
                    result.success("TaskStart")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This even doesn't work when I test it in onCreate method.
I used flutterEngineCache from mainAtivity and then I use the cached flutter engine in the service class same as in MainActivity.

I also set my AndroidManifest.xml to use the service in proper way

```kotlin
import android.app.Service
import android.content.Intent
import android.os.IBinder
import android.util.Log
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngine
import io.flutter.embedding.engine.FlutterEngineCache
import io.flutter.plugin.common.*

class TaskService : Service(), MethodChannel.MethodCallHandler {
    private val CHANNEL_HANDLER = "buddhism.supporter.onTaskRemoved"
    private lateinit var backgroundEngine: FlutterEngine

    override fun onBind(intent: Intent?): IBinder? = null

    override fun onCreate() {
        super.onCreate()
        Log.wtf("onServiceBind", "Service binding")
        backgroundEngine = FlutterEngineCache.getInstance().get("engine_id")!!
        MethodChannel(backgroundEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger,
            CHANNEL_HANDLER
        ).setMethodCallHandler{
            call, result ->
            if (call.equals("endService")) {
                result.success("success")
            } else {
                result.notImplemented()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onTaskRemoved(rootIntent: Intent?) {
        super.onTaskRemoved(rootIntent)
        Log.wtf("ontaskRemoved", "onTaskRemoved")
//        backgroundEngine = FlutterEngine(this)
//        channel = MethodChannel(backgroundEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL_HANDLER)
//        channel.setMethodCallHandler {
//            call, result ->
//            Log.wtf("task end","task end in android")
//
//        }
//        channel = BasicMessageChannel(backgroundEngine.dartExecutor.binaryMessenger, CHANNEL_HANDLER, StringCodec.INSTANCE)
//        channel.send("onTaskRemoved")
        Log.wtf("ontaskRemoved", "onTaskRemovedAfter")
        stopSelf()
    }

    override fun onMethodCall(call: MethodCall, result: MethodChannel.Result) {
        Log.wtf("task end","task end in android2222")
        if (call.equals("endService")) {
            result.success("success")
        } else {
            result.notImplemented()
        }


    }

}
```

Comment: What is the error/exception you are facing?

Comment: I didn't get any error/exception just the setMethodCallHandler didn't communicate with MethodChannel in flutter. I tried to log in the setMethodCallHandler but it didn't log anything.